# How can I get my AWS MYSQL pool to connect to node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I get: Error: Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database, when trying to connect via a connection pool to my AWS MySql database.

I've triple checked the database credentials, so this must be either syntactical or methodical.

database is a MySql RDS on amazon web services and I'm using the express middleware on node js.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = require('../lib/db');

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()
  server.use(cors());

  server.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM products'
    pool.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
          return result.json({
                data: rows
          })
        }
    )
})

...
```

db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'XXX',
    user: 'XXX',
    password:'XXX',
    database: 'XXX'
})


pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }    if (connection) connection.release()    

    return
})
module.exports = pool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, being relatively new to Node.js and MySql, I wasn't as confident in my syntax as I should have been. It was a methodical issue.

When creating a connection pool, you have to have the name of the database. For some reason, AWS will give you a "database instance" and put "-" for the DBName. Thus I assumed they were of the same value.

I used MySQL Workbench to extract the Database Name, which is entirely different to the DB Instance I entered on Amazon.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Node.js so don't really say if the code or syntax is correct, but i get what you're trying to accomplish.

A middle ware which connects applications to a db, using a pool of connection.

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

This project might help you more than i can.
Its related to the same concept.

Comment: Hello! I am importing the mysql package in the above code and using it to establish the connection pool. I've managed to figure it out. Cheers for taking a look though.